# Using Tableau Prep to add 0 values

Tags: tableau-desktop

Suppose I have the data

Date        Person  Sales 
15/01/2021  Peter   10
15/02/2021  Peter   20
15/03/2021  Peter   10
15/04/2021  Peter   30
15/05/2021  Peter   40
15/06/2021  Peter   20
15/01/2021  Sally   20
15/03/2021  Sally   10
15/05/2021  Sally   50

Sally made 0 sales in 02, 04, or 06, so no one input any sales data for her. However, when I clean the data, I would like for her to have three extra rows for when she made 0 sales so that the data says

Date        Person  Sales
15/01/2021  Peter   10 
15/02/2021  Peter   20
15/03/2021  Peter   10
15/04/2021  Peter   30
15/05/2021  Peter   40
15/06/2021  Peter   20
15/01/2021  Sally   20
15/02/2021  Sally    0
15/03/2021  Sally   10
15/04/2021  Sally    0
15/05/2021  Sally   50
15/06/2021  Sally    0

Does anyone know how to accomplish this quickly in Tableau prep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for doing that is to identify your time granularity (say month) and create a flat file having all the dates you need:

```
15/01/2021
15/02/2021
...
15/12/2021
```

Then from you original datasorurce you may want to create a step with Tableau prep in order to have the distinct users:

```
Peter
Sally
```

Then you need to join those two temp tables in order to have the cartesian product:

```
15/01/2021 Peter
15/02/2021 Peter
...
15/12/2021 Peter

15/01/2021 Sally
15/02/2021 Sally
...
15/12/2021 Sally
```

Once you have that table you just need to add a column for sales (or the other metrics you need to use) with a zero/null values according to your need(probably null works better when it comes to avg and not just sum):

```
15/01/2021 Peter null
15/02/2021 Peter null
...
15/12/2021 Peter null

15/01/2021 Sally null
15/02/2021 Sally null
...
15/12/2021 Sally null
```

With this final temp table you just need to create a union using your original datasource and that final table, and you will have all your original data plus a backup just in case some user may miss any monthly row.